# Is there a way to dynamically change CPU count for a docker container at runtime?

Tags: docker

I want to know if there is any functionality provided by docker or a functionality of Linux that can be leveraged to change the CPUs that have been assigned to a docker container at runtime ?

For example:

I run an image named test:1.0 by binding it to say 2 cores out of 4:

```
$ docker run --cpuset-cpus=0,1 test:1.0
```

Now, this guarantees me that the container will have 2 cores with 100% utilization capacity. What I would like to do is to change the container's allocated CPUs at the runtime. So I would like to give 1 more core to it if I feel that no other process is using it. Or decrease its already given cores by 1 if I feel that some other process requires it. The container should keep running during this change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command (you will have to provide your container id, of course):

```
docker update --cpuset-cpus="0"
```

That will update it runtime! There is a lot of old, out of date information on the internet which says you can't do this. It might only work on Linux docker, though.

Comment: Great, works like a charm on MacOS, docker 2.1.0.4!